# What permissions will require manual update?

Tags: android, google-play

In Play Store: I want to add new permission to my app, how can I tell if this will require manual update from the user(Assuming that this user got his auto-update apps turned on)?

There are a few related outdated questions about this:

- [Permissions changes requiring manual update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437514/permissions-changes-requiring-manual-update)
- [What kind of Android application will require android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966864/what-kind-of-android-application-will-require-android-permission-read-phone-stat)

Answer (score 2):

Manual update of the app will not depend on the changes you will make on your app. It actually depends on the settings that the user set for your app as to whether it will automatically get updated or not.

Now, assuming that the user turned the auto-update on for your app, The behavior will vary depending on the android version of the device. For devices running Android 6.0 and up, the application will still be updated automatically (without asking the user) and permissions must be requested and handled at runtime.

For lower versions (Android 5.9 and below), user has to accept only the new permission upon application update.

These are discussed in the google support page below
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602