# Do "normal" permissions addition on android 6+ break auto updates via Google Play?

Tags: android

I would like to add the following permissions to my android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to `25`. The `minSdkVersion` is set to `16`.

These two permissions are labeled ["normal"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) permissions which are granted automatically. So I don't need to ask the user to approve these permissions. But will this change break the auto-update feature via Google Play for my app when I release it?

Thanks

Comment: there's no `compile target`. Either you mean `targetSdk` or you mean `compile Sdk`. Two **different** things esp. when talking about permissions

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski you're right, updated.

Comment: for completion and what is your minSdk?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it's set to 16.

Comment: check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17048414/3178395